# How to simplify a polygon down to X amount of points?

Tags: postgis

If I have a polygon that has 100000 points, how can I calculate what the tolerance should be to simplify it down to 1000 points using ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology?

Comment: by trial and error using bisection

Comment: Are you asking if you can calculate, a priori, if it is possible to derive a relationship between tolerance and percentage point reduction? My understanding of Dougles Peucker is that you would need to essentially run the algorithm to derive this information. An iterative approach in a loop ought to do it.